# MySQL privileges for PHP server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask maybe a stupid question, but still: if I have php server that communicates with MySQL and it is protected against injection attacks, is it still important that I set privileges for each and every user separately? Or all that matters is that I have already set basic privileges for all users? e. g. no "DROP ALL DATABASES" stuff. Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate it!

Comment: every user should have no more privileges than they absolutely need

Comment: As @Dagon says, you should follow the principle of least privilege. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: most setups would only have one user anyway

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thank you all, sorry for not responding, you were right - I will pick one right answer, but all of you had a point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't steal something that doesn't exist**

Don't give hackers the ability to manipulate anything (db information, code, privileges, etc.)

---

### You can never be too safe

- [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)
- [XSS Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)